# Vue js + Hateoas Module

Tags: vue.js, hateoas

I will start to learn Vue.js and want to use it for consuming an HATEOAS compilant API, but found nothing that make it easier

Is there some Vue.js module for consuming HATEOAS compilant Rest APIS?

Answer (score 1):

Not Vue specific but [traverson](https://github.com/traverson/traverson) seems to be the best choice around.